# sed: screen resolution from xdpyinfo

Tags: sed

```
xdpyinfo  | grep 'dimensions:'
dimensions:    1280x800 pixels (301x188 millimeters)
```

I'm interested in keeping only second string from the above output, namely 1280. How can I do that using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
xdpyinfo  | sed 's/^ *dimensions: *\([0-9]*\).*/\1/;t;d'
```

The `\(  \)` capture the data matched between themselves, and this is then referenced with `\1` in the replacement value.

The commands after the `s` (substitution), `t;d` delete lines that have not matched the substitution expression (`t` will cause the script to jump back to the beginning if `s` did not match, thus skipping `d` (delete line).

Comment: Almost but not exactly - output from the above command is 1280x800 and I need only 1280.